# FTL attribute list filtering issue

Tags: freemarker

I'm working on building my store in ecwid and doing some very basic modifications to the html based email confirmation templates that they provide. They use [FTL](https://freemarker.apache.org/) for accessing a number of variables regarding product information - their main literature is [here](https://support.ecwid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009415719#available-variables-for-store-information).

**Goal**

I would like to be able to use an "attribute" which is hidden from the product page but important for the email output - namely, providing a download link/code automatically on order confirmation. The language to access this is as follows:

```
<#list orderItem.attributes as attribute> 
<p>${attribute.value} </p>
</#list>
```

where the <#list> item pulls in the attributes for the relevant product and ${attribute.value} reads out whatever hidden value I've stored in the relevant attribute.

**Problem**

However, the issue that I'm having is that the code above will list ALL attributes for a given product, and I have been unable thus far to filter the attributes to just the one I need (they have "UPC" and "Brand" attributes which are system generated and cannot be deleted). So, for the sample attributes / values below:

```
attribute_name | value
UPC | 83888924
Brand | Nike
download_code | www.download.com/code
```

The code listed would produce the following:

```
83888924
Nike
www.download.com/code
```

whereas I need code that will output only `www.download.com/code`

**Tried so far**

Based on the FTL in their (ecwid) literature and the FTL website, I have tried things like:

`${attribute.value[2]}` : yields the third character of each value, but still all three values

`${attribute[2].value}` : yields nothing and seemingly breaks all of my code

`<#if ${attribute.attribute_name} == "download_code"><p>${attribute.value}</p></#if>` : yields nothing and seemingly breaks all of my code

**End**

I assume I'm missing something very basic here; is anyone able to help?

Comment: Solved: correct syntax is as follows:
<#if attribute.name == "insert name here">

Also just has to be inserted at the right place, I.e. above any content block or <td> if you're inside a table etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation the name of the attribute is `attribute.name` instead of `attribute.attribute_name`.

The correct syntax is:

```
<#if attribute.name == 'download_code'><p>${attribute.value}</p></#if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried this actually (I changed the name of the field for explanation purposes here) and I didn't have success regarding using attribute.name instead of attribute.attribute_name; however I see you're using single quotes around download_code so I can give that a shot.